# Unable to build ionic app using the ibm-mfp-push cordova plugin on Android (conflict with google-analytics cordova plugin)

Tags: ionic-framework, google-analytics, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services, google-analytics-firebase

I've been developing an Ionic app for several months, successfully using the [ibm-mfp-push](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-cordova-plugin-push) plugin for Push Notifications.

I would now need to use the [cordova-plugin-google-analytics](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin) plugin.
I've added the plugin to my project and was able to make it work properly on iOS.

But when trying to build the project for android, I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzpz;
```

Seems like there is a conflict between ibm-mfp-push and cordova-google-analytics.

Could someone please provide some help?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project and build it again in AS?

Comment: Yes I did. Same result in Android Studio as when doing a _ionic build android_

Comment: Could you upload your Gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

Right now adding this Google Analytics plugin for Cordova does result in a conflict with the `ibm-mfp-push` plugin -- I am able to recreate and confirm. I've let the service team know.

For the time being, I recommend using the native solution for Android.